# Print web page to PDF in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, visual-studio-2012, printing, html

For a school project I have to print webpages to PDF in C#.
I can do this manually by pressing ctrl+p in chrome en choosing save as pdf.
I want to do it with my program because I have to print 30000 web pages.
An example of a webpage I have to print is "http://prf.icecat.biz/?shopname=openIcecat-url&smi=product&vendor=HP&prod_id=D8G49AAE&lang=nl"
I'm new around here so if I didn't give enough information, please ask.

The code also looks quite special to me, it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="light_wrapp">
<div id="light_title_description">
This is a demo of a seamless insert of an Icecat LIVE product data-sheet in your website. Imagine that this
responsive data-sheet is included in the product page of your webshop. <a
href="https://icecat.biz/get_attachment.cgi?6752" target="_blank">How to integrate Icecat LIVE JavaScript.</a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="loadLiveIcecat"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="liveIcecatData"
data-icecat_id=""
data-brand="HP"
data-part_code="D8G49AAE"
data-ean_upc=""
data-language_code="nl"
datasignature="
gn4vxXU3uI7JPKzL1RNoPAFGPRYdNmwmWJ5FeQj1J45Ba2qiaVYgoE%2FEXwpjaBSdKTrk%2F
%2ByI0AiT5CW1bk3r6SmHY%2FdUuQN3fss8h0se8w9mSw7FDr8SWvqoawB3m69lt6Ske4n%2F01IpEFO9Y
QEVpW9kFZRPWH%2Fuy0yuIbDdm4pd7%2BT9XbPFEk0fKGRH57Nkj5%2FvNEiMW1JhdzV86rJR5ME11j3P
0PJhBMGT1tm2AA0uiDILSNuOwnTWc2WVFEHzC4xr8Q591rPC%2B%2Bue230VowhLLmZTczheEGWrTCA
Wl%2B5Fj4qeLjLe3qTq1MxQaqSIUJXG5rz0BdR%2Fe8ZwkMNAgQ%3D%3D"
data-timestamp="1453663924"
data-shopname="openIcecat-url"
>
</body>
</html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/themes/basic/css/icecat/demo.css" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://live.icecat.biz/js/live-current.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://prf.icecat.biz/themes/basic/js/icecat/live/init.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can try using itextsharp, an open library that allow you to convert HTML content into PDF.

Comment: I tried it, but I get the HTML code as text in the pdf.

Comment: The HTML code looks also quite special to me.

Comment: If you tried it and it didn't work, please show us what you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ABCpdf,a third-party library.

[ABCpdf api document](https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/)

It make webpag2Pdf easy.

```
Doc theDoc = new Doc();
theDoc.AddImageUrl("http://www.google.com/");
theDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("htmlimport.pdf"));
theDoc.Clear();
```